# Twitter JSON Access with API V1.1

Tags: json, twitter

With the somewhat recent update to the Twitter API, links for JSON pages don't seem to work anymore. I'm wondering how I can get a link similar to this one: http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=apple (which would find tweets about apple). This link is broken (as you'll see if you click on it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes your link is deprecated now, the link would be like this for api v1.1:

> https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=apple

PS: You will need to create an account then authorize your application.

Answer (score 0):

The Twitter oauth API V1 is deprecated completely as of late June. You need to change your code API V1.1 which allows you to view the content in the json file via authentication only. 
 Like @meda said, you need to have an application to run it with.

Once creating an application at twitter, you can use any twitter oauth library to collect the data from the json files.

ASFIK,https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth [Abraham's twitter oauth] is the best for starters to learn the flow of authentication and easy access of twitter informations.